# Z-score percentages

Tags: statistics

I have no idea how to do these problems. Can someone walk me through them? step by step?

1. Suppose that you are a special education coordinator for a school district that mandates that all children with an IQ score below 85 should be placed in a special education classroom. What percentage of children would that be? Hint: The mean of a distribution of IQ scores is 100, and the standard deviation is 15.
2. Using the same information as above, consider the educator that would like to develop a program to meet the needs of children with IQ scores of 125 or above. What percentage of children would that be?
3. Using the same information in question #1, what is the IQ of a child if she was in the top 55% of the popuation?

Comment: It'll be good to include what you have tried so we can see where you are having problems with.

Comment: I just don't know how to start the problem off. I just need someone to explain how to start it to get started.

Comment: Do you have  a decent statistics text? I strongly recommend the Schaum's guides which have many many solved problems and illustrations. This question is very basic and is just an application of a simple formula and table. You need to read the instructions and apply the rule. An illustration helps.
To start, here is a simple but useful introduction
https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html
Here's a useful table:
http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf
Here are some worked examples
https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/standard-score-4.php

Comment: "A start" is all we can do without more context. Unless you show an attempt to use your standard normal table, we can't know the style of table you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to start with #1.

You have $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\, \sigma=15)$ and you seek
$P(X < 85).$ You can solve this directly with software, or by standardizing
and using printed normal CDF tables.

In R statistical software, for example:

```
 pnorm(85, 100, 15)
 ## 0.1586553
```

By standardization: If $X$ is the 'raw' IQ score, then the corresponding
'standard' score is $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}.$ Accordingly, we can solve
the problem as follows:

$$P(X < 85) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{85-100}{15} \right)
= P(Z < -1),$$

where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution. I don't know what style
of normal tables your text has, but you can look at the explanation and
figure out how to evaluate $P(Z < -1) = 0.1586,$ using such tables.

Problem #2 is much the same.

Problem #3 involves using normal tables
'backwards'. Note that $c$ such that $P(X > c) = .55$ implies $P(X < c) = .45.$ Search in the body of the table for the nearest value to 0.4500
(or, depending on the style of table, perhaps 0.0500). Then look in the
margins of the table to get the $c$ 'cut-off' point on the standard scale, and solve for the IQ score. The exact answer from
software is shown below; you can get 'pretty close' using normal tables.
For example, note that $\frac{d-100}{15} = c = -0.13$ implies $d = 98.05.$

```
 qnorm(.45)           # standard normal
 ## -0.1256613
 qnorm(.45, 100, 15)  # X ~ NORM(100, 15)
 ## 98.11508
```